# How set elements to localStorage in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage

I try to learn react-redux and i coding a new project. I want, When I click to Add Favorites button, push to all column data in localstorage. I try to read lots of article but none of my answer my question. They are easy examples.
So here is my code. What should I do ?

```
  isFavorite() {
    var obj ={movieImage:"", movieTitle:"", "year" : ""};
    localStorage.setItem('obj ', JSON.stringify(obj ));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.dataStart();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        {isData && _.map(movies.data, (movies, index) =>
          <Grid.Column key={index}>
            <Card.Group>
              <Card>
                <image src={movies.image} />
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <button onClick={this.isFavorite.bind(this)}>Add to Favorite</button>
                  </div>
                  <figcaption className="cap">
                    <p>{movies.movieTitle}</p>
                    <p>{movies.year}</p>
                  </figcaption>
                </div>
              </Card>
            </Card.Group>
          </Grid.Column>
        )}
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Im not quite clear on what you  are trying to achieve here. Do you want to store data and retrieve it?.

Comment: Yes. I want to push data to localstore and retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following hopefully, it would help you

```
     isFavorite=()=> {
       var movies= [{
          movieImage: "ss.png",
          movieTitle:"matrix", 
          year : 2010
        },
       {
         movieImage: "ss.png",
         movieTitle:"matrixs", 
         year : 2019
      },
      {
        movieImage: "ss.sssssspng",
        movieTitle:"masssstrix", 
       year : 2010
      }
     ];
           localStorage.setItem('movies', JSON.stringify(obj ));
          }
          componentDidMount() {
            this.props.actions.dataStart();
          }
          render() {
            return (
              <Grid>
                {isData && _.map(movies.data, (movies, index) =>
                  <Grid.Column key={index}>
                    <Card.Group>
                      <Card>
                        <image src={movies.image} />
                        <div>
                          <div>
                            <button onClick={()=>this.isFavorite()}>Add to Favorite</button>
                          </div>
                          <figcaption className="cap">
                            <p>{movies.movieTitle}</p>
                            <p>{movies.year}</p>
                          </figcaption>
                        </div>
                      </Card>
                    </Card.Group>
                  </Grid.Column>
                )}
              </Grid>
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: thank you, but there is more than one element, about 20 movies.

Comment: you can add multiple movies as well you should add object inside the object {{movieImage:"hdhd.jpg", movieTitle:"matrix", year : "2011"},{movieImage:"hdhd.jpg", movieTitle:"matrix1", year : "2010"},{movieImage:"hdhd.jpg", movieTitle:"matrix2", year : "2013"}}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this you can **stringify** the array and save it in local storage. when you wan to retrieve try something like i have done in `loadIsFavorite()` method. , make sure you **parse** is while retrieving.

```
     isFavorite=()=> {
            let arr =[{movieImage:"hdhd.jpg", movieTitle:"matrix", year : "2010"},{movieImage:"hdhd1.jpg", movieTitle:"matrix1", year : "2011"}];
            localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(arr));
     }

     loadIsFavorite=()=>{
         let arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites"));
         //do something
     }

     componentDidMount() {
          this.props.actions.dataStart();
     }

     render() {
            return (
              <Grid>
                {isData && _.map(movies.data, (movies, index) =>
                  <Grid.Column key={index}>
                    <Card.Group>
                      <Card>
                        <image src={movies.image} />
                        <div>
                          <div>
                            <button onClick={()=>this.isFavorite()}>Add to Favorite</button>
                          </div>
                          <figcaption className="cap">
                            <p>{movies.movieTitle}</p>
                            <p>{movies.year}</p>
                          </figcaption>
                        </div>
                      </Card>
                    </Card.Group>
                  </Grid.Column>
                )}
              </Grid>
            );
          }
        }
```